# Block Older Version of iOS

Tags: ios

My application is running in iOS 5,6 and 7. Now I want to block for iOS 5.Application should run in only iOS 6 and 7.so is it possible?If yes then how to do? PLease help me.Thanking you.

Comment: you have to upload new version with deployment target 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Deployment target in the build settings to the minimum iOS version you require.

A general guideline is to set:

-Base SDK to latest

-deployment target to the minimum version you support.

Also - check your Info.plist file for the MinimumOSVersion key.

Comment: MinimumOSVersion  key or InfoDictionary version key?

Comment: InfoDictionary isn't related to what you are asking.

Comment: InfoDictionary is something else, don't touch that ;)

Comment: No worries, Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 2):

you set your Deployment target to the minimum iOS version you require[image]

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html), you can set this as Deployment Target.

Go to your project -> General -> Deployment Target, this works as a minimum deploy version needed to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can release a new version with a higher [Deployment Target](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW21).  That will restrict the app so that only users on the version you specify or higher can install the new version of your app.

Users who have already installed the old version your app will continue to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

just change deployment target to the minimum version you support.and Base SDK in Build   Setting and something more in info.plist just check it and set your Deployment Target

Answer (score 0):

Tap on the project in the left menu.
Then, be sure you're on the project and not on the target and change the iOS Deployment Target to the one you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install an old XCode version like 4.5 or earlier because the new XCode 5 supports only iOS 6.1 and iOS 7 or later.